# Store int value into char* - C++?

Tags: c++, casting, memcpy

I have allocated a block of memory as (char *), in which I want to be able to store an integer.

```
char * arr = new char[50];
int num = 9;

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++)
{
      *((int *)arr) = arr[i];
}

memcpy(&arr, &num, sizeof(num));

cout<<"Contents of arr: "<<arr<<endl;
```

I seem to be getting a segmentation fault whenever I compile however. How can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: I thought I would need to cast those (char *) bytes into int bytes first in order to write an int into that block of memory, but I'm guessing it's wrong.

Comment: There are multiple issues with your code. Why are you iterating from 0 to `sizeof(int)`? Why are you copying values _from_ `arr` back in to `arr`? You have a syntax error with the loop's closing brace - `]` in place of `}`. As requested in the "[how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" code must be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop is unnecessary.  I'm not sure what it is trying to accomplish.  The memcpy is ok except that you're taking the address of arr which is already a pointer.  This will work:

```
char * arr = new char[50];
int num = 9;

memcpy(arr, &num, sizeof(num));

cout<<"Contents of arr: "<< ((int *)arr) <<endl;
```

Perhaps your for loop was trying to do this:

```
char * arr = new char[50];
int num = 9;

*((int *)arr) = num;

cout<<"Contents of arr: "<< ((int *)arr) << endl;
```

That would be ok, too.

Edit: The contents of the array are not printable directly, at least not with any meaning (and may crash because of no zero termination).  Assuming you want it to look like an integer, I've edited the code above.  C++ purists will probably object to using a C style cast instead of reinterpret_cast<>, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: Thank you! So I don't get the segmentation fault any more, but what happens is that my output displays, `"Contents of arr: 0xfc76230"`, (after I change `num` to equal 10). Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: DO not forget to take into account potential aligment issues.

Comment: Yes, alignment is definitely an issue for this method in general.  There isn't any guarantee that new char[50] will be int-aligned, although it will be on most compilers.  It would be better to pull the value back out into an int before using it.  memcpy is a safer way to pull the value in and out of a buffer if you're on a platform that is picky about alignment.